# Hunger Bar Won't Go Down

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing on the Xbox One and just downloaded the new version with the Better Together installation. I'm playing alone, started the game in survival, normal mode. The hunger bar isn't going down. Is there something else that could cause this now? Is anyone else having this issue? It was working fine this afternoon on another world.

Comment: What version are you playing?

Comment: There is the minecraft-pocket-edition tag so I am gonna guess he is playing minecraft PE @Fabian

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. I'm playing the new version that just came out on the xbox one update( I believe it was an update for the xbox one edition) along with the better together installation.

Comment: I didn't edit the tag. I put the tag in as just Minecraft.

Comment: Ah then you are playing the windows edition build, which is the same on xbox, pc and also mobile

Comment: I edited the tag. And with my question I don't mean "edition", I actually mean "version". Like 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, etc. Which version are you playing?

Comment: I know what versions I have on my pc, but when it comes to my xbox one I have no clue what version it is. I bought the minecraft disc in the store, a thing popped up yesterday asking if I wanted to play the new Minecraft and I clicked the button to install it. Then I also installed the better together update. I thought it was the same updates that  everyone else was playing on xbox one.

Comment: Have you tried eating rotten flesh?

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden meter called *saturation* which has to empty before hunger starts going down. It's refilled by eating, though by how much depends on the food and is not related to how much hunger it fills. Pro tip: golden food is the best in terms of saturation.

Answer (score 0):

it may just be a small glitch, or you just haven't played or ran far or long enough, my advice, enjoy while you can, get food and get stocked, then when your hunger bar does go down you have food, its a good glitch and will probally help you more then agitate or irritate you, for now you don't have to worry about food, but do carry food at all times just so when it does start going down you can fill it and not starve.

Comment: I've been playing Minecraft for about two years. I made it to level 8. Having to search for food in survival is an added bonus when you are trying to survive. lol It's very frustrating so I went to difficult and still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are in Peaceful mode. Your hunger doesn’t go down in Peaceful.

Answer (score -3):

You may be in peaceful mode, try switching difficulties.

Comment: The OP said they are in survival mode, and on normal.